# Pass 'content' from ArrayController to another Route/Controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

What is the right pattern to pass the 'content' from one ArrayController (Route) to another Controller (Route)? And make it even available in a third controller?

Answer (score 0):

Inside a controller/Route, all controllers are available. This can be accessed via controllerFor. So, there is no need to pass properties of one controller to another one.

Inside one controller, content of another controller can be accessed like this:
var sampleContent = this.controllerFor('sampleArray').get('content');

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_controllerFor

Comment: And how to i render this 'content' in the second view? Here is what I have: 
http://jsfiddle.net/WWj9D/

Comment: when is the startcontroller in the fiddle gets loaded with content? (Call createRecords method inside startroute.)

Comment: OnClick the StartView triggers 'createRecords' and transitionsTo PhotoView. The var 'content' is available in StartController. But in PhotoView this.get('content') is empty – so nothing is rendered to the screen

Comment: Is the StartView getting destroyed while transitioning? How the startview is connected to the startcontroller? Does the route transition to startview happen through startroute or through embercontainerview currentviewbinding? In the latter case, the view will get destroyed and corresponding controller will also get destroyed.

Comment: The transition happens via '@transitionTo 'photos', @objectAt(0)' in the IntroController. Everything is 'autoconnected' via the Router.

Comment: I've create a new thread with a jsfiddle here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969353/emberjs-1-0-how-to-create-models-and-display-them-in-another-route