# Emberjs 1.0: How to create Models and display them in another route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'am trying to create a collection('content') in one route and pass them to another route to display them. What's wrong here?

> Error: "content in StartView undefined"

**Here is the code**

http://jsfiddle.net/insnet/cmBgz/21/

```
App = Ember.Application.create({LOG_TRANSITIONS: true});
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application'
});


/* Routing */
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("start", {path: '/'});
    this.route("photos");
});

/* Start */
App.StartController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    createModels: function() {
        this.set('content', Ember.A());

        this.addObject(Ember.Object.create({id: 1, title: 'Hello'}));
        this.addObject(Ember.Object.create({id: 2, title: 'Digital'}));
        this.addObject(Ember.Object.create({id: 3, title: 'World'}));

        this.transitionToRoute('photos');   
    }
});

/* Photos */
App.PhotosView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    contentBinding : 'App.StartController.content',

    didInsertElement : function() {
        console.info("content in StartView", this.get('content'));
    }

});


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <div class="contrainer">
          <div class="hero-unit">
    <h1>My App</h1>
    {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="start">
    <h2>View:Start</h2>
    <button  {{action "createModels"}} class="btn btn-primary">Create models and goto '/photos'</button>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="photos">
    <h2>View:Photos</h2>
    {{#each controller}}
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/cmBgz/22/

At first, this were the **mistakes/misunderstandings** in the fiddle:

1 - This Binding does not work because you are referencing the controller class, not the instance that is created by the Ember framework.

```
App.PhotosView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    contentBinding : 'App.StartController.content',
```

2 - The log message in your View was wrong and cannot work that way. If you want to access the 'underlying thing' of a view, always use the property 'context'. The term content is just used in conjunction with controllers.

```
/* Photos */
App.PhotosView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement : function() {
        console.info("content in StartView", this.get('context.content'));
    }

});
```

**This are possible solutions to your problem:**

a - This is a possible way to lookup your instance of startController and set its content as content of the generated controller for the photos route:

```
App.PhotosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(){
        var startController = this.controllerFor("start"); //in routes you have access to controllers with this method
        return startController.get("content");
    }
});
```

b - Another possibility would be to declare the controller for the route manually und use Ember Dependency Injection (**likely the most "emberish" solution**):

```
App.PhotosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs : ["start"], // "I need the startController plz!" -> accessible via "controllers.start"
})

/* The corresponding each in your template would look like this */
{{#each controller.controllers.start}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling with this for days!

Comment: Here is a good introduction into the new "needs" solution: http://www.kaspertidemann.com/calling-a-controller-action-from-a-view-via-the-needs-api-in-ember-js/